# MYSQL Mapping Letter Grade to its Equivalent Value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables DEPORTMENT and DEPORTMENT_VAL.

```
TABLE DEPORTMENT
idnumber | subjectcode | 1st Qtr | 2nd Qtr | 3rd Qtr | 4th Qtr
1        | CL 7D       | A-      | A+      | A       | B+
1        | ENG 7D      | A+      | A+      | A+      | B+
1        | MATH 7D     | B+      | A-      | A+      | B+

TABLE DEPORTMENT_VAL
Grade | Value
A+    | 1
A     | 2
A-    | 3
B+    | 4
```

What should I query so that I can show this view?

```
TABLE DEPORTMENT
idnumber | subjectcode | 1st Qtr | 2nd Qtr | 3rd Qtr | 4th Qtr
1        | CL 7D       | 3       | 1       | 2       | 4
1        | ENG 7D      | 1       | 1       | 1       | 4
1        | MATH 7D     | 4       | 3       | 1       | 4
```

Update: I changed the DEPORTMENT table by quarters because I need to get the average of these grades per quarter after I get this view.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM DEPORTMENT
JOIN DEPORTMENT_VAL USING (Grade)
```

Comment: It worked in this sample tables but when I did this on my actual tables where there are more details, it shows blank.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbldeportment` (
  `schoolyear` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `idnumber` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `subjectcode` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `dateeval` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  `facultyid` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q01` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q02` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q03` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q04` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finals` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnumber`,`schoolyear`,`subjectcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbldeportment_val` (
  `q01` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`q01`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

Comment: @Ingvaru Do not post aditional info into a comment, edit/update the question instead. *when I did this on my actual tables where there are more details, it shows blank.* I predict that according columns have different names (`q01` columns have different datatypes - so joinig column in `tbldeportment` is not `q01`) - use ON clause with proper joining condition instead of USING().